# change time output in bash script

Tags: bash, time

How to change this time output ?

```
date --date="@$(echo $(TZ=UTC date +%s) - $(date +%s)'%(5*60)-(5*60)' | bc)"
```

Output: **za apr 12 00:25:00 CEST 2014**

Should output in this layout: **%Y%m%d%H%M**

How to implement this in the string ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks but that gave me a really strange output, i have tryd that before.: date: invalid date ‘@2014041122311397255100’

Comment: Can you please show your expected output?

Comment: za apr 12 00:35:00 CEST 2014
201404120035

Comment: d="@$(echo $(TZ=UTC date +%s) - $(date +%s)'%(5*60)-(5*60)' | bc)"&&echo \`date --date="$d"\` \`date --date="$d" +%Y%m%d%H%M\`

Comment: Thank you this works, but the time format is not UTC i see... it makes no sense if i change UTC is something else. date --date="@$(echo $(TZ=UTC date +%s) - $(date +%s)'%(5*60)-(5*60)' | bc)" +%Y%m%d%H%M

Comment: Please, elaborate.. Oh, you want it in utc? i updated my answer.

Comment: Yep, our local time is UTC+2... and its now 1:05 But i need UTC time... that would be 23:05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this should do what you want:

```
d="@$(echo $(TZ=UTC date +%s) - $(date +%s)'%(5*60)-(5*60)' | bc)"&&echo `date --date="$d"` `date --date="$d" +%Y%m%d%H%M`

d="@$(echo $(TZ=UTC date +%s) - $(date +%s)'%(5*60)-(5*60)' | bc)"&&echo `date --date="$d" --utc` `date --date="$d" +%Y%m%d%H%M --utc`
```

Second one is in UTC.

Comment: Wow this works for me, you make me a very happy person!! Last question, how to get this in a variable ? When i echo $d it returns a strange string! @1397257200

Comment: Yeah, that's what you pass to date, to get it into a variable you do `var=$(d="@$(echo $(TZ=UTC date +%s) - $(date +%s)'%(5*60)-(5*60)' | bc)"&&echo \`date --date="$d" --utc\` \`date --date="$d" +%Y%m%d%H%M --utc\`)`.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, you don't need `TZ=UTC`, since `date +%s` returns seconds since 1 January 1970 UTC, so it's the same, regardless if you specify a timezone there. What the internal command does is get the reminder from `date +%s`/300(5 minutes), subtract that from `date +%s` and then subtract 300 from that.